# Drop-down menu doesn't get pushed down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, hover

I have created a Navigation bar that when you hover over the link "Social" a drop down menu appears. It does appear, but it creates more padding on the bar and the content isn't pushed down like a normal Drop-down menu. Here's the jsfiddle. Thank you anyone who replies.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn7f55sj/)

```
 body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#nav {
  background-color:#222;
}
#nav_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a,visited{
  color: #ccc;
  display:block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color:#ccc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
#nav ul ul{
  display:none;
  poisition:absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 5px solid #222;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul ul li{
    display:block;
}
# nav ul ul li a,visited{
  color: #ccc;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover{
  color:#099;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in line#44. `poisition` should be `position`.

Comment: All you need to do is give you unordered list inside the social a tag a position of absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will fix it:

```
#nav ul ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 5px solid #222;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

The issue being `position` has been spelt incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
position:absolute;
```

You wrote

```
poisition:absolute;
```

https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/oYarzW